# Chrome does not send cookies when using Range http header

Tags: google-chrome, iis, cookies, http-headers

I have a pdf document (~2MB), which can be open only after user authentication.

User logs in, and requests the pdf file in the browser (displayed in the browser, not downloaded)

1st Request:

```
/docs/secure/test.pdf
```

Chrome sends all the cookies (as expected) and the server responds with code 200 and:

Response 1:

```
...
Accept-Ranges: bytes
...
```

After that, Chrome sends another request for the remainder of the file:

Second Request initiated by the browser:

```
...
Range: bytes=786432-1429583
...
```

but with this request it does **NOT** send any cookies, which is a problem because the server (IIS) cannot authorize the request and returns Code 302 with a location header:

```
Location: /login?ReturnUrl=xxxx
```

As a result - only the first page of the pdf is displayed in the browser.

Why is the browser not sending the cookies with the second request?

Can anything be done to overcome this?

Comment: What version of your chrome? It could be a bug in Chrome. You can try to `SameSite=Lax`, and then test.

Comment: tested with 84 and today it updated to latest 85 - same issue.

Comment: @samwu - the SameSite attribute should not matter for same site requests, right? so, it should not matter in my case because all requests are towards same site.

Comment: Do you encounter the same problem in other browsers?

Comment: No, Firefox and IE open the file at once. Only Chrome is doing several requests

Comment: That is the problem of chrome, I suggest you go to the chrome forum for help.